# Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Protocol

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ethernet

I couldn't find any information about this protocol, other than the fact it can be used for NIC teaming (how or why was not specified).

Can anyone tell me more about it? For instance, what does it do and how does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Protocol**
>
> Can anyone tell me more about it? For instance, what does it do and
>   how it works.

In short after reading up on it from several different resources...

When you configure your server for (and enable)
**NIC Teaming**, this is essentially a virtual IP address which is accessible on your LAN (bi-directional).

Additionally, it contains the rules\algorithms to follow for the NIC teaming
configuration as you specify to assist in conforming TCP/IP traffic
accordingly [<sub>[Source]</sub>](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30160) such as:

- - NIC teaming architecture
  - Bandwidth aggregation (also known as load balancing) mechanisms
  - Failover algorithms
  - NIC feature support – stateless task offloads and more complex NIC
    functionality

---

**Research, Reading, and Resources:**

- [4SysOps](https://4sysops.com/archives/nic-teaming/)
- [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997031.aspx)
- [TechNet Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2012/06/19/nic-teaming-in-windows-server-2012-brings-simple-affordable-traffic-reliability-and-load-balancing-to-your-cloud-workloads.aspx)
- [Windows Server 2012 NIC Teaming (LBFO) Deployment and Management](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30160)
- [Set-NetLbfoTeam](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130844(v=wps.630).aspx)
- [New-NetLbfoTeam](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/jj130847(v=wps.630).aspx)
- [802.1AX-Rev - Link Aggregation Revision](http://www.ieee802.org/1/pages/802.1AX-rev.html)
- [Wikipedia Link Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation)